# Why I am unable to access the zen-cart website in my laptop?

Tags: zen-cart

While accessing the zencart-home page I am getting this error on browser in my laptop - what would be the problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't have a problem accessing that page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a temporary issue on zencart's site. Nothing with your laptop.
This might have already fixed as I can browse it now :)

Cheers